# What is the different between this 2 .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On 

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

SSLRequireSSL

SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "testurl.com"

ErrorDocument 403 https://testurl.com
```

**AND**

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testurl.com/$1 [R,L]
```

What is the difference, and which is preferable or 'better'?

Comment: Why the down vote? i want to know what this do and how it works.

Comment: This may have been downvoted because (a) there is no introductory paragraph, (b) the code has not been formatted, (c) questions about what is "better" may be regarded as discursive, and so off-topic.

Comment: First time he ask **what is the different between**. why do not you explain it to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example only redirect the domain from the `HTTP` protocol to `HTTPS`.
With this example you open the Site with following URL: `http://testurl.com/my_shop/article.html` will be only redirected to `https://testurl.com/`

The Second Rewite-Rule redirects the complete requested URL to the `HTTPS` protocol. If you navigate to `http://testurl.com/my_shop/article.html` you will be redirected to `https://testurl.com/my_shop/article.html`

The basic probem of the first example is, the user will be redirected to the main page and lost the desired page